# What information is used to encrypt web.config in IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, encryption, web-config

Let's say I have a connection section in my web.config like this

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=xxxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx;Enlist=false;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I follow the instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky.aspx) to encrypt it, and it becomes something like this

```
<connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
    <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
      <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
      <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
          <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
          <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <KeyName>Rsa Key</KeyName>
          </KeyInfo>
          <CipherData>
            <CipherValue>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</CipherValue>
          </CipherData>
        </EncryptedKey>
      </KeyInfo>
      <CipherData>
        <CipherValue>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</CipherValue>
      </CipherData>
    </EncryptedData>
</connectionStrings>
```

So far everything works.

But here's the thing. I have a lot of different apps running on the same server using the exact same connection string section. It would be really convenient to just copy and past the encrypted section onto all the web.configs, but when I try it just produces a 500 error.

Apparently something about the encrypted data is specific to a particular directory. I'm aware that the encryption key is specific to the computer, but these are all on the same server using the same key, so I'm wondering if anyone knows more about how the encryption works and why you can't copy-and-paste from one sub directory to another.